# “Structure->Block” showing when permission is not given to user

Tags: 8, users

I have user role 'Admin', who can see 'taxonomy terms' under 'Structure', I have given same permission but it is showing 'Block' and 'Views' too.

Is there any workaround in Drupal 8?

[image]

[image]

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You've probably given them the *Administer blocks* and *Administer views* permission as well. Withdraw these permissions and the links should disappear.

[image]

[image]